# Issue parsing JSON file with Go

Tags: json, go, get

I make a GET request, and receive a JSON file, that I cannot parse.

Here is the data I have to parse

```
{
    "codeConv": "ACC00000321",
    "start": "2019-07-01T00:00:00Z",
    "end": "2019-08-21T00:00:00Z",
    "details": [
        {
            "idPrm": "30000000123456",
            "keys": [
                {
                    "timestamp": "2019-07-01T00:00:00Z",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "timestamp": "2019-07-01T00:30:00Z",
                    "value": 0
                },
                ...
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "idPrm": "30000000123457",
            "keys": [
                {
                    "timestamp": "2019-07-01T00:00:00Z",
                    "value": 1
                },
                {
                    "timestamp": "2019-07-01T00:30:00Z",
                    "value": 2
                },
                ...
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here are my objects:

```
type APIMain struct {
    CodeConv string          `json:"codeConv"`
    Start    string          `json:"start"`
    End      []Keys          `json:"end"`
    Details  []APIData `json:"details"`
}

//APIData match the data we receive from api
type APIData struct {
    Prm  string `json:"idPrm"`
    Keys []Keys `json:"keys"`
}

type Keys struct {
    Timestamp string `json:"timestamp"`
    Value     string `json:"value"`
}
```

and here is the method to get data with basic auth:

```
tr := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    }
    client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if login != "" && password != "" {
        req.SetBasicAuth(login, password)
    }

    response, err := client.Do(req)
    //defer response.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if response.StatusCode != 200 {
        fmt.Println(response.Body)
        panic(response.Status)
    }

    err = json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&result)
    fmt.Println("result", result) // result is empty array
```

How can I see if the problem is in a request, or if the problem is in parsing ?

I have get a `response.Body` object, but it needs to be decoded.

Comment: The response JSON is not an array but an object, so if you're passing `result` which is an array according to your comment (*"result is empty array"*) then that's your problem.

Comment: ... it would be easier to help you if you show the declaration of the `result` variable.

Comment: You shouldn't use or print `result` without checking the error return `err`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using: https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

which generated this structure:

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    CodeConv string    `json:"codeConv"`
    Start    time.Time `json:"start"`
    End      time.Time `json:"end"`
    Details  []struct {
        IDPrm string `json:"idPrm"`
        Keys  []struct {
            Timestamp time.Time `json:"timestamp"`
            Value     float64   `json:"value"`
        } `json:"keys"`
    } `json:"details"`
}
```

Thanks for your comments

Great time saver !